# Pure Web AS3 project use only AIR SDK in Flash Builder 4.7

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

After a long delay, I decided to create a new AS3 web project (for Flash player in HTML page, not AIR). However, it now uses only AIR SDK and I can not change it. I need the Flex SDK, which is installed and easily used to create Flex projects. But now I need a pure AS3 project.

What happened? 
Any advice would be great!Thanks.